# Pine Script Strategy Stoploss and Takeprofit problem

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I tried to code a strategy with Stoploss and Takeprofit. After the signal bar, the entry (blue Line), stoploss (red line) and takeprofit (green line) are declared.

Problem 1: When a position is entered, the stoploss is triggered. Even if the red line is not touched by the price. What am i doing wrong? (compare Imagelink) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO1aT.png)

[image]

Problem 2: When a position is closed, a new position is entered at the next bar. Even if the price is higher than the entry price (blue line). These buys should not happen. (compare Imagelink) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGnp8.png)

[image]

Here my Code:

```
//Stoploss + Take profit
SL = input.float(0.5, step=0.1) 
TP = input.float(2.5, step=0.1)

buyprice = BB_high
longstop = BB_high - (BB_high - BB_low)*SL
longprofit = BB_high + (BB_high - BB_low)/2 * TP

plot (longstop, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot (longprofit, color=color.green, linewidth=2)

//Position entry + exit (stoploss or takeprofit)
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, stop=buyprice) 

if strategy.position_size >0
    strategy.exit (id="Long SL", from_entry="Buy", limit=longstop)
    strategy.exit (id="Long TP", from_entry="Buy", stop=longprofit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit` for take profit and `stop` for stop loss. You got those mixed up.

```
strategy.exit (id="Long SL", from_entry="Buy", stop=longstop)
strategy.exit (id="Long TP", from_entry="Buy", limit=longprofit)
```